# UIContainerView height of content (embedded UITableViewController)

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder, autolayout

I currently have a UITableViewController embedded in a UIContainerView in Interface Builder. Is there a way to set the height of the UIContainerView to the content's height (using prototype cells)? Basically, what I want is to have a UIScrollView around my UIContainerView, and set some AutoLayout rules to my UIContainerView so that the height gets calculated from the number of cells inside, and the parent UIScrollView adjusts accordingly its scroll area.

**Edit**

Thanks to the great answers, ended up changing the frame height using this code:

```
    alarmsTableViewController.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    println(alarmsTableViewController.tableView.contentSize.height)
    alarmsContainerView.frame.size.height = alarmsTableViewController.tableView.contentSize.height
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Programmatic intervention is required: UITableViews are of course UIScrollViews, and nested scrollviews aren't going to be able to size themselves in AutoLayout. It's a legitimate ambiguity, because AutoLayout won't know to make the frame smaller and require more scrolling or the frame bigger and less scrolling. In your case, you want the latter with no scrolling.

The simplest way to solve this is to create a constraint for the height of the TableView (or its container view). This will act on the frame of the tableView, and if set to larger than the content size in any direction (only vertical in tableviews) the scroll view won't scroll. Best add it/modify it in the view that contains the tableView. Then access the table view's contentSize property. The actual code is very simple:

```
-(void)updateViewConstraints {
    self.tableViewHeightLayoutConstraint.constant = self.tableviewInMyScrollView.contentSize.height;
    [super updateViewConstraints];
}
```

If everything else in the scrollview has heights & widths that are fixed by the time the AutoLayout engine operates, this should automatically size the scrollview for its content.

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation. Ended up overwriting the frame directly, since my containerView with the tableView is already in a tableFooterView (whoa, complicated stuff :]). See my edit.

Comment: Hm, usually a hard-and-fast piece of advice is that setFrame won't provide information to the layout constraints. But this scrollviews-in-scrollviews is such a wonky area even before the last detail about the tableFooterView, it could be doing something that gets that information out there, glad I could help.

Comment: Well, since I'm not feeding the setFrame height value to the layout constraints (since this is not really possible inside a tableFooterView), this is all good :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What i do in my projects is inside `-(void)updateViewConstraints` on your ViewController update a constraint given by an `IBOutlet` depending on number of cells inside the tableView. For example:

```
-(void)updateViewConstraints{
   float newHeigh = ([self.array count] + 1) * 84;
   self.topViewHeightConstraint.constant = newHeigh + 540;
   [super updateViewConstraints];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I thought about calculating using the height of my cells, but since it's now much easier to use autolayout for cells height, I found this solution a bit fragile. Ended up using contentSize of tableView.